# How to use OpenNTF's "Workflow for XPages"?

Tags: workflow, xpages

Any tips on getting started using the "Workflow for XPages" on OpentNTF?  The documentation is pretty high-level, and mostly about the sample app.  Page 24 is the only one with info about using the simple workflow engine.  I'm digging into the EmployeeReview.nsf example database, but could use some pointers?

Comment: You should probably post on the OpenNTF project page asking the question. Liable to get a faster answer from the developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my developers evaluated the workflow stuff over the last couple of days. Unfortunately, I cannot share the documentation that came out as a result of her efforts.
So the only way for you by now is to analyse the parts of the sample application.
Find the Simple Workflow Control und Workflow Action controls in the sample application and take a look at the source code. 
You will see that the Simple Workflow Control deals with persons and roles. Roles in the context of workflow are not ACL Roles. They are roles that ere defined in the configuration ( like [Manager] )
So you need to have some kind of configuration in your application that contains a person name an the role this person has in your workflow. If this person is a manager for example, you have also to describe, which other persons he/she is managing.
Then, in your workflow steps you describe, in which wf state a specific person is involved, what is the next step and if any mail is send around.
Once ayou have done a bit of analysis, you will be able to create your own sample application. 
I also hope that there will be more documentation around. I will provide more detailed information about how to use the wf controls, but I'm going on holiday in the next days. So I do not have much time left, to put a manual together.

But looking at the source code should help to understand how all the stuff works.

Comment: Ulrich, thanks for the info, and Simon, yes I'll post it over at the OpenNTF project page.